# Weird behavior of two fruits' names (ananas/pineapple, banana/plátano)

Tags: language-change, evolution, cognates

Some time ago I found two tables that reported the names for two fruits, which were supposed to be funny, because they specifically reported a single exception among those several languages, where this fruit's name was different for only one of those languages.

I cropped the images to avoid space problems:

[image: the fruit that is ananas in many languages is pineapple in English only][image: the fruit that is banana in many languages is plátano in Spanish only]

They make one smile, but if we try to analyse the matter under a Linguistics point of view, it gets interesting, deserving to have a look into it.

**So my questions are**:

1. Why did two languages, English and Spanish, develop an alternative word to denote those fruits?
2. And why did just one language (per case) behaved like this? I mean, why not also some other Romance language for one case or some other Germanic one for the other case?

---

<sup>**N.B.** I just asked one question because I think these two occurrences are related, but if someone finds out they are two different linguistic phenomena, I can split them up. Also, feel free to retag, if necessary.</sup>

Comment: @aedia λ thanks for the edits, the title one is good, I didn't think of it! :)

Comment: this page (about the case for the word "tea") might give you some insight http://wals.info/chapter/138

Comment: Maybe slightly off-topic, but "piña" is Spanish for pinneapple too, together with "ananás". I don't have data about how much each of these terms are used and where. But in Spain, "ananás" is virtually never heard. This means that the table that you show on the left-hand side is, at least, questionable.

Comment: Spanish has lots of words for bananas and plantains and what may or may not be perceived as extra distinctions between and beyond them depending on which country you're in: *la banana*, *el banano*, *el cambur*, *el guineo*, and *el plátano* plus derived kinds like *plátano macho* and *plátano malayo*.

Comment: @CesarGon Thanks for the contribution. I didn't make the tables myself, I just reported what was on the internet :) But anyway, it's just one language, it doesn't make it less questionable than it was before, since there are also other languages that don't use "ananas".

Comment: @Alenanno: I am aware that you didn't create the tables yourself. I was just trying to contribute extra details.

Comment: @CesarGon And thanks for posting! I mean, being Spanish, you did the right thing posting. I just said it to be clear, not just for you. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: Don't assume Spanish is special in being the only one under-represented in the list. How can you know what else didn't make it without also having access to the list of rejections?

Comment: @hippietrail You assume that I *wanted* English and Spanish to be the only cases. But it's wrong. I simply didn't thought of other cases, like I didn't thought about it being a loanword case. But that's also why it's a question on here: I wanted to ask if something linguistic was going on and we have it. If Spanish is slightly different and if others are different, is not really important (apart from my first question), we still had a really high number of cases where the word was always the same.

Comment: @Alenanno: No I didn't make such an assumption at all.

Comment: @hippietrail I wrote it too strongly perhaps. :) Anyway, maybe I should have asked if those tables were "right" before asking about a linguistics process. I could write this but I don't want to ruin these long answers. What do you think?

Comment: I think in this case bad initial data led to very good answers, but it makes me wonder whether the site is more intended for linguists asking linguists about hard stuff or interested laypeople asking linguists about easy stuff... or both.

Comment: @hippietrail well I think both, as long as the topic is stimulating. I think this one was interesting enough, even if it turned out to have kind of a simple answer.

Comment: @Alenanno: Absolutely, no problem. ;-)

Comment: We call it anannas in Urdu too

Comment: Are none of the below answers worthy of being accepted? It seems that we have some thoroughly researched answers that seem correct.

Comment: When I say "correct" they are the prototypical kind of "good answer" we expect here: not just one-sentence answers, but documented, researched, thoughtful explications of the questioner's post. Maybe they aren't what the questioner was looking for. But that doesn't mean they aren't good answers; in fact, sometimes answers reveal that the question was based on incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Who ever said they weren't good answers? I didn't, certainly. They are both great answers but I'm still unsure on which one I should accept.

Comment: @Alenanno Ok, that's fine! I just saw they had been answered back in October and was hoping they hadn't been forgotten. This was a good question.

Comment: @MarkBeadles No no it wasn't forgotten... :D I'm just struggling lol

Answer (score 36):

I'm going to answer about just the words for "pineapple".  In short, you're seeing two phenomena:

- A **new item** is introduced to the world, so a **new name** is needed to go with it.  Whichever name is used by the introducers gets adopted in many other languages.  See *coffee* or *computer* for some other examples of this.
- The dataset you have above only includes examples that show the author's intended pattern and **excludes examples that don't fit**.

Let's start by looking at the dataset.  Clearly there's a bias towards *ananas*-type words than towards *pineapple*-type words, but we don't know why.  One possibility is that the collector of this dataset simply included only languages with *ananas* and discarded any examples of *pineapple* (apart from English).

So let's get some data of our own.  I'm using Google Translate to pull up words for pineapple in all the languages they provide.  (With a few restrictions: there must be a result other than what I typed in English, and there must be a romanization available.)

- Afrikaans: pynappel
- Armenian: ark’ayakhndzor
- Azerbaijani, Belarusian, Bulgarian, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, Finish, French, German, Icelandic, Italian, Macedonian, Maltese, Norwegian, Polish, Romanian, Russian, Serbian, Slovenian, Swedish, Turkish, Ukrainian: ananas
- Basque, Galician, Spanish: piña
- Bengali: Ānārasa
- Catalan, Filipino: pinya
- Chinese: bōluó
- English: pineapple
- Estonian: ananass
- Georgian: ananasi
- Greek, Portuguese, Slovak: ananás
- Gujarati: Anēnāsa
- Haitian: anana
- Hindi: Anannāsa
- Hungarian: ananász
- Indonesian, Malay: nanas
- Irish: anann
- Japanese: Painappuru
- Kannada: Anānas haṇṇu
- Korean: pain-aepeul
- Latvian: ananāsu
- Lithuanian: ananasas
- Swahili: mananasi
- Tamil: Aṉṉāci
- Telugu: Anāsa paṇḍu
- Thai: S̄ạbpard
- Vietnamese: dứa
- Welsh: phîn-afal

At a glance, it looks like we have six basic types here:

- ananas: 42 languages
- piña/pineapple: 10 languages
- ark’ayakhndzor: 1 language
- bōluó: 1 language
- S̄ạbpard: 1 language
- dứa: 1 language

Clearly the *ananas* words are the most common, but what does that mean?  Should Serbian and Croatian (which are generally mutually intellible) each get a "vote" while Mexican Spanish and Castilian Spanish have to share a "vote"?  Which languages you count and which ones you don't is fairly arbitrary.

Let's break this up a different way.  The pineapple only came to the Old World via European colonization of the New World, so let's see what the European colonizers call this fruit.  Here we're only looking at languages whose parent countries had a major colonial presence in the New World before 1600:

- Portuguese: ananás
- Spanish: piña

One of these languages use a *pine*-type word, one uses an *ananas*-type word.  Doing a bit of reading, it seems that *ananas* is the Guaraní word for "pineapple" and was borrowed by the Portuguese, and it spread from there.  The Spanish (going all the way back to Columbus) called the fruit *piña* "pine" because of its resemblance to a pinecone.

From these two origins come many of the names for "pineapple" in the various languages of the world.  The only phenomenon you're seeing here is that *ananas* simply became more popular.  My best guess as to the distribution of the two forms would be the dominance of French (with *ananas*) in previous centuries.  Languages that are more heavily influenced by Spanish (like Filipino) end up with *pine*-type words.  Languages more heavily influenced by English (like Japanese) end up with the full *pineapple* type.

Comment: Note that Columbus was italian, not spanish, but I get your point on that. :P Plus, the spanish also use ananas, so... But you're basically saying it's a loanword, nothing more, right? I was starting to think there was something more behind it, without even thinking about the simplest reason. :P

Comment: By the way, can you put those names in a tab? Your answer is too long to scroll this way. :)

Comment: I'd love to put the words in a tab, except that I have no idea what that is or how to do it... Sorry, I'm new to the site.

Comment: I mean, you make a table in some editing program you have, make a screenshot and post it here as an image. :)

Comment: Just a side note: In Brazilian Portuguese, the fruit is more commonly known as "abacaxi" (a word that probably comes from the Tupi language).

Comment: Same goes for potato. The whole indo-european world  calls potato variously as potato, batata, patata, etc. but in northern India, potato is called "Alu" in Hindi, Bengali, Punjabi, etc. I have read that Alu comes from Persian, which means 'round'.

Comment: @NikhilBellarykar, quite a few European languages have their own words for potato: French *pomme* was extended from its original meaning of "apple", German *Kartoffel* from a word for a mushroom, Slovak *bandurka* probably meaning "lumpy", etc.

Comment: Oh. I was under the impression that almost all European languages use variants of potato. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Joe Since both you and Floating Tone gave very good answers, but still incomplete, I was thinking of merging the most important parts in your answers in a CW answer and accept that, but upvote **and** obviously attribute the parts to you two because the work was yours and not mine. I just want to do this so I have a single answer to accept. Both your answers are great, but they address a different side, so I don't know where to turn. Let me know here what you think. :)

Comment: @Alenanno, that's fine with me.  I'm just glad I could help.

Comment: @Joe Thank you! By the way, since the answer will be a Community Wiki, everybody is allowed to edit more than the usual posts. I'll trust you to double-check the things I attribute to you, so you make sure I don't misunderstand any of the info you provided. :)

Comment: Columbus was Italian, but on a Spanish voyage.

Comment: @Joe I have a little off topic comment here, but nevertheless as a Slovak, I found your choice for the translation of potato very interesting (where did you actually find it ?). Most Slovaks would probably not understand you. That word is very regional. Typical translation that everyone knows is "zemiak" (zem = earth/soil, so maybe something like coming from earth/living in the ground).

Comment: @jcxz that's what my family calls them.  What region is *bandurka* used in today?

Comment: @joe I am not really an expert on this, but I believe the region is north-east Slovakia (the region of Spiš and Šariš, close to polish border). That is where my father is from and I know the word from his family.

Comment: @jcxz, that makes sense.  My ancestors emigrated from Žakarovce, near Prešov.

Comment: @joe : The french name of potato is indeed “pomme-de-terre” (=earth-apple), but we also use “patate” as a more familiar term. By the way, I think it’s quite unusual in French to have two names for the same vegetable

Answer (score 22):

@Joe has covered words for "pineapple", so here's some info on words for "banana".

There is a fairly straightforward explanation for why Spanish has the word *plátano* instead of a variant of *banana*, compared to the other languages in the above list.

*Plátano* already existed in Spanish to refer to another sort of plant, namely the ['plane tree'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus), or trees of the genus *Platanus*, whose name can be traced back via Latin through Greek to a Proto-Indo-European root *plat- "to spread". The name is thought to refer to either the largish leaves some of these trees have, or their broad, flat expanses of bark.
Various cognates also carry the meaning of 'broad', 'spreading', and so on - in English,  plants of the genus *Plantago*, commonly called *[plantains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantago)*, are similarly named for their broad, round leaves, via a borrowing from French. *(Edit: to clarify, the plantains just mentioned are a small, herbaceous, bog-loving plant, completely unrelated to any sort of banana).*

So, once the Spanish-speaking world had access to bananas, *plátano* was usefully extended to refer to (some) banana plants; given that banana trees have quite enormous leaves, the name is quite appropriate.

There is an alternative hypothesis that Spanish got *plátano* from the Carib word *platana* (from Arawakan *pratane*) and that this was altered to make it more similar to Spanish *plátano* 'plane tree', but there is not much evidence to support this, and either way *plátano* 'plane tree' is somewhat responsible.

But, the list above is a bit disingenuous, because Spanish **does** have the word *banana*, and this is the word that Spanish initially borrowed from Wolof, a Niger-Congo language, to refer to the fruit. Depending on what sort of Spanish you speak, *banana* can refer to to smaller, sweeter fruits we are most familiar with, while *plátano* might refer to the larger, starchier, less sweet fruits that are generally used in cooking rather than eaten raw. In English, the latter are referred to as *[plantains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantain)* or *plantain bananas* (probably on analogy with Spanish *Edit: because although English already had the word 'plantain', it wasn't used to refer to bananas*). Both sorts are of the genus *Musa*. But at least in Mexico, *plátano* refers to the sweet variety, and plantains are *plátano macho*.

Most modern languages that use a variant of the word *banana* got the word via either Spanish or Portuguese, and those languages initially borrowed it from Wolof. So, to reiterate Joe's point, "whichever name is used by the introducers gets adopted in many other languages".

But in fact, the history of 'words for banana' started long before the Spanish and Portuguese borrowed the modern word from Wolof, and if you look at languages across the world, the word *banana* hardly comes into play.

A recent study by a team of geneticists, archeologists, agricultural scientists and linguists investigated the history of different banana varieties based on the evidence for human cultivation and dispersal of bananas. The evidence suggests that bananas likely originated in New Guinea, and the linguistic information associated with this is pretty interesting. Mark Donohue  put together a list of over 1,100 words for 'banana' in languages from Melanesia and South East Asia, the regions in which the banana was first dispersed. The paper can be accessed [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/28/11311) (sorry, abstract only unless you have access), but the supplementary materials are available publicly, so **if you want to see over 1,100 words for 'banana'**, [go to this page and click the link for Table_S04](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/28/11311/suppl/DCSupplemental).

Using comparative methods, the researchers reconstructed root forms for different words for 'banana', and found four major cognate sets with distinct, but overlapping, geographical distributions. The root forms were *muku, *punti, *qaRutay, and *baRat. [You can see some maps of the distribution of these variants here (pdf).](http://www.pnas.org/content/suppl/2011/06/28/1102001108.DCSupplemental/sfig05.pdf) There were other minor groupings and a lot of 'miscellaneous' lexical items that had no clear group of cognates. *Banana* is labelled as such, and only shows up twice in this whole list (granted, the list doesn't include many African or continental European languages).

In sum, while *plátano* is an oddity in the short list presented above, Spanish actually did use the word *banana* first, and some varieties of Spanish still do use it for sweet bananas, where *plátano* specifically refers to plantain bananas. Furthermore, crosslinguistically, *banana* is actually an oddity in itself.

Comment: I wish we could favourite answers independently of questions here (-:

Comment: Great answer! I just don't understand “In English, the latter are referred to as plantains or plantain bananas (probably on analogy with Spanish)”. I don't see the relation with Spanish here. Earlier you said that “plantain” comes from the French. The French uses for this fruit both « plantain » (in Africa) and « banane plantain » so I only see in the English usage clear loans from French...

Comment: @JPP, sorry for the confusion - in the first mention of 'plantain' in English, I am talking about a completely different, non-banana plant (have a look at the link), for which the name did (apparently) come from French. What I meant later was that English started using 'plantain' to refer to bananas on analogy with Spanish (they had the word already, but didn't use it for bananas). Do my edits clear that up?

Comment: Though of course, the French may have extended 'plantain' for bananas first, and then English also extended the meaning on analogy with French, rather than Spanish. Either way, both French and English used the word for something completely different before anyone had ever tasted a banana :)

Comment: @FloatingTone +1 for a nice exhaustive answer. For the record, in Central America (Panama at least) *platanos* refer to the *plantain* and *guineo* to the *banana*. While the former is used as a vegetable - it is starchy and usually toasted (Dom Rep => tostones) or fried, the latter is eaten as a fruit. Mistaking one for the other is a sure way for a "gringo" like myself to provoke hilarity.

Comment: @FloatingTone: that's OK: it was just an excuse to tell you how awesome I found your answer...

Comment: @FloatingTone Since both you and Joe gave very good answers, but still incomplete, I was thinking of merging the most important parts in your answers in a CW answer and accept that, but upvote **and** obviously attribute the parts to you two because the work was yours and not mine. I just want to do this so I have a single answer to accept. Both your answers are great, but they address a different side, so I don't know where to turn. Let me know here what you think. :)

Comment: Please, feel free - it's the best way to make a comprehensive answer that can be accepted for this :)

Answer (score 6):

The reason that "only one language" calls it a "pineapple" is that the table left out other languages which also do. Spanish, for example, calls it *piña*, and a quick glance at [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pineapple#Translations) suggests that several other languages, including Welsh, Catalan, and Afrikaans, do too. It's not surprising that many different languages would have only two words for the fruit, because it's a new world fruit and those are all old world languages, so they all take it as a loan-word.

As for banana, it seems that many, many languages have different words for it. See [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/banana#Translations) and note in particular the geographical variation in the Spanish word.

The moral of this story is that if we pick the right samples we can show anything.

Comment: ie The table used would not be considered a good source by linguists. Linguists would demand something better.

Answer (score 2):

*Banana republic* is said ''república bananera'' in Spanish, even in Spain and not ''república platanera''. ;)
Some people in Spain differentiate between a *plátano* and a *banana*, just like many people in Portugal use both *abacaxi* (for Brazil-imported pineapple) and *ananás* (for other pineapples).
*Plátano* as a word is never really used in Central America or in Argentina. For example, the Argentinian Clarin dictionary considers it a Mexicanism.

*Plátano* and *banana* in Spanish, as well as *ananás* and *abacaxi* in Portuguese are like
*anguria* and *cocomero* in Italian, there is no one single universal word for the fruit, there are only regional preferences.
German had a similar ''problem'' with Apfelsine and Orange, but now Apfelsine (a NorthGerman word) is considered obsolete, and Orange (with French pronunciation) is almost universally used. In Argentina, ''ananá'' is more frequent than ''piña'' (and the plural is: ''ananás'').

Answer (score 1):

Re: ananas

The origin of the word is Brazilian (from Guarani),but in Brazil the pineapple is commonly called abacaxi, not ananas.  Only the Portuguese regularly distinguish between ananas and abacaxi (the latter to indicate a large Brazilian pineapple)

Comment: Your question concerns the origins of specific words and so does not address the more general topics that linguistics addresses.    I think it's off-topic.

Comment: Some photos: [abacaxi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIy8a.jpg) [JPG] and [ananás](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfXqt.jpg) [JPG]. These are **not** really the same fruit.

Answer (score 0):

For what I know Ananas in the Arawak language means "flower in the flower" ana = flower The name came with the first encounters with the Taino people in the Caribbean islands that were usually eating these fruits

Answer (score -2):

But why is it called pineapple in English when so many other languages call it ananas or similar? Pointing out that there are others that don't exactly call it ananas, while helpful, misses the elephant in the room. Pineapple isn't anything like ananas.

The reason stems from the practice of medical botanists naming unfamiliar new world fruit as apples. Captain John Smith was one the earliest to record the word for the tropical fruit in 1624. It may be Smith that recalled the things that grew on pine trees when he saw the fruit so he called it a pineapple unaware that everyone was already calling it ananas.

Comment: The fruit had already been called _nana_ or _anana_ in English prior to 1624 – and more importantly, it had already been commonly named _piña_ in Spanish after pine cones for nearly a century. Smith and others who started calling it a pineapple in English almost certainly did so inspired by Spanish usage. Also, this question is 12 years old, and the question of _why_ English used a different word had already been addressed in several other answers.